# How to position the appearing text in place of the last image avatar?

Tags: html, css

Hello guys i'm asking why my last image avatar, is when i'm dragging my mouse in the last avatar the text appearing in the top of it, it supposed to be inside the avatar like the other avatar the text is inside of the image. Can anyone help? thank you guys

Also the top of the last centered avatar is when i drag my mouse over there, there are no text appearing it supposed to appear a text like the other avatar that when you drag the mouse the text appears

```css
img {
    border-radius: 50%;
  }

  table,
  th,
  td {
    border: 10px solid black;
  }

  .container {
  position: relative;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
  }

  .image {
    opacity: 1;
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    transition: .5s ease;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
  }

  .middle {
    transition: .5s ease;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 3%;
    transform: translate(17%, -20%);
    -ms-transform: translate(50%, 50%);
    text-align: center;
  }
  

  .last {
 position: relative;
    float: none;
    margin: auto;
 
    
  }

  .container:hover .image {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
   .text {
   background-color: #dbe0dc;
   color: black;
   font-size: 16px;
   padding: 10px 20px;
 }
 .column {
   float: left;
   width: 33.33%;
   padding: 5px;
 }
}
 .container:hover .image {
   opacity: 0.5;
 }

 .container:hover .middle {
   opacity: 1;
 }
```

```html
<center>
<div class="container">
<img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145908/preview2/52eabf633ca6414e60a7677b0b917d92-male-avatar-maker.jpg" class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
<div class="middle">
    <div class="text">avatar 1</div>
  </div>
  </div> <br>
 <div class="container">
<img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145908/preview2/52eabf633ca6414e60a7677b0b917d92-male-avatar-maker.jpg" class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
<div class="middle">
 <div class="text">avatar 2</div>
</div></div>
 <div class="container">
<img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145908/preview2/52eabf633ca6414e60a7677b0b917d92-male-avatar-maker.jpg" class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
<div class="middle">
 <div class="text">avatar 3</div>
</div></div>
 <div class="container">
<img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145908/preview2/52eabf633ca6414e60a7677b0b917d92-male-avatar-maker.jpg" class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
<div class="middle">
 <div class="text">avatar 4</div>
</div></div>
 <div class="container">
<img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145908/preview2/52eabf633ca6414e60a7677b0b917d92-male-avatar-maker.jpg" class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
<div class="middle">
 <div class="text">avatar 5</div>
</div></div>
 <div class="container">
<img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145908/preview2/52eabf633ca6414e60a7677b0b917d92-male-avatar-maker.jpg" class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
<div class="middle">
 <div class="text">avatar 6</div>
</div></div>
 <div class="container">
<img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145908/preview2/52eabf633ca6414e60a7677b0b917d92-male-avatar-maker.jpg" class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
<div class="middle">
 <div class="text">avatar 7</div>
</div></div>
 <div class="container">
<img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145908/preview2/52eabf633ca6414e60a7677b0b917d92-male-avatar-maker.jpg" class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
<div class="middle">
 <div class="text">avatar 8</div>
</div></div>
 <div class="container">
<img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145908/preview2/52eabf633ca6414e60a7677b0b917d92-male-avatar-maker.jpg" class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
<div class="middle">
 <div class="text">avatar 9</div>
</div></div>
 <div class="container">
<img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145908/preview2/52eabf633ca6414e60a7677b0b917d92-male-avatar-maker.jpg" class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
<div class="middle">
 <div class="text">avatar 10</div>
</div></div>
 <div class="last container">
<img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145908/preview2/52eabf633ca6414e60a7677b0b917d92-male-avatar-maker.jpg" class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
<div class="middle">
 <div class="text">avatar 11</div>
</div></div>
</center>
<div id="wrapper" class="last container">
 <audio id="mytrack"  controls style="width:250px">
  <source src="audio . com" type="audio/mp3">
 </audio>
 <nav>
  <div id="defaultBar">
   <div id="progressBar"></div>
   </div>
</nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change from:

```
.last {
  position: relative;
  float: none;
  margin: auto;
}
```

to:

```
.last {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
```

[`inline-block`](https://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_inline-block.asp):

> does not add a line-break after the element, so the element can sit
>   next to other elements.

```css
img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 10px solid black;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}

.image {
  opacity: 1;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  transition: .5s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.middle {
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 3%;
  transform: translate(17%, -20%);
  -ms-transform: translate(50%, 50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.last {
  /*position: relative;
  float: none;
  margin: auto;*/
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}

.container:hover .image {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.text {
  background-color: #dbe0dc;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 5px;
}

/*} /*<< notice extra {*/*/

.container:hover .image {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.container:hover .middle {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145908/preview2/52eabf633ca6414e60a7677b0b917d92-male-avatar-maker.jpg" class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
    <div class="middle">
      <div class="text">avatar 1</div>
    </div>
  </div> <br>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145908/preview2/52eabf633ca6414e60a7677b0b917d92-male-avatar-maker.jpg" class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
    <div class="middle">
      <div class="text">avatar 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145908/preview2/52eabf633ca6414e60a7677b0b917d92-male-avatar-maker.jpg" class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
    <div class="middle">
      <div class="text">avatar 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145908/preview2/52eabf633ca6414e60a7677b0b917d92-male-avatar-maker.jpg" class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
    <div class="middle">
      <div class="text">avatar 4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145908/preview2/52eabf633ca6414e60a7677b0b917d92-male-avatar-maker.jpg" class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
    <div class="middle">
      <div class="text">avatar 5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145908/preview2/52eabf633ca6414e60a7677b0b917d92-male-avatar-maker.jpg" class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
    <div class="middle">
      <div class="text">avatar 6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145908/preview2/52eabf633ca6414e60a7677b0b917d92-male-avatar-maker.jpg" class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
    <div class="middle">
      <div class="text">avatar 7</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145908/preview2/52eabf633ca6414e60a7677b0b917d92-male-avatar-maker.jpg" class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
    <div class="middle">
      <div class="text">avatar 8</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145908/preview2/52eabf633ca6414e60a7677b0b917d92-male-avatar-maker.jpg" class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
    <div class="middle">
      <div class="text">avatar 9</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145908/preview2/52eabf633ca6414e60a7677b0b917d92-male-avatar-maker.jpg" class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
    <div class="middle">
      <div class="text">avatar 10</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="last container">
    <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145908/preview2/52eabf633ca6414e60a7677b0b917d92-male-avatar-maker.jpg" class="image" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
    <div class="middle">
      <div class="text">avatar 11</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</center>
<div id="wrapper" class="last container">
  <audio id="mytrack" controls style="width:250px">
  <source src="audio . com" type="audio/mp3">
 </audio>
  <nav>
    <div id="defaultBar">
      <div id="progressBar"></div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```